# MySql And variables to exclude resultset

Tags: mysql, variables

I have a doubt on how variables work in   mysql. As I read in their web looks like setting a variable will become visible to the next row.

My table is like:

```
A     B     C      N
1    NULL   NULL   4
1    NULL   NULL   4 
1     1     NULL   4 
1     1     NULL   4
1     1     1      4
1     1     1      4
```

What I want is to return only the rows with `C = 1`. If no rows then return `B = 1 and C is NULL` if no rows `A = 1 and B is NULL and C is NULL`.

My idea was:

```
select N as number,
       @var_c := case when (C = 1) then 1 else -1 end as myc,
       @var_b := case when (@var_c < 0 and B = 1) then 1 else -1 end as myB,
       @var_c := case when (@var_a < 0 and var_b < 0 and C = 1) then 1 else -1 end as myC

from (select @var_a := -1) r_a,
     (select @var_b := -1) r_b,
     (select @var_c := -1) r_c,
     (select A, B, C, N from my_table order by A desc, B desc, C desc) rows
```

It should (I want to) return

```
number     myA    myB    myC
  4         -1      -1    1
  4         -1      -1    1
  4         -1      -1    -1
  4         -1      -1    -1
  4         -1      -1    -1
  4         -1      -1    -1
```

With this and `having myA > 0 or myB > 0 or myC > 0` would work.

But it is returning

```
number    myA     myB    myC
  4         1      -1    -1
  4         1      -1    -1
  4         -1      -1    1
  4         -1      -1    1
  4         -1      1    -1
  4         -1      1    -1
```

Shouldn't Mysql keep the vars across the rows?

Regards.

Comment: Actually, I've used sqlvars in many queries throughout S/O.  The basis is that the from clause you can do a bunch in a single ( select AtVar1 := 0, AtVar2 := 0, AtVar3 := 'test', AtEtc := 'more' ) sqlvars.  Then, if you want a variable adjusted, you do as you have, and the new value is available for the next row in the query.  However, can you provide some true sample data of what you have vs expected results you want.  I DO understand your criteria though.

Comment: @DRapp I actually gave a sample of my table. And what I wanted. Thanks for your comment

Comment: ok, then let me ask this. If there is even a SINGLE row that has C = 1, do you NEVER WANT any A or B qualifiers (one query)?  Or on a per row basis, each gets determined to be included or not based on the NULL value or not.  This would allow many rows, but include ALL that qualify for EITHER C=1, or C=NULL and B=1 or C=NULL and B=NULL and A=1.  Your result set COULD include all 3 (of these types of records).  Which version DO you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, do not use variables like this. You shouldn't expect that you can set a variable in a `FROM` clause and then access the value in the `SELECT` clause. That's not how variables work. Normally you should only use a variable in one place in the query, otherwise you can get undeterministic results.

Second of all, why don't you just issue three different queries? First for `A = 1 and B is NULL and C is NULL`, and if it doesn't return any rows, issue a query with the second condition set. And so forth.

And if you ultimately want to issue just a single query, you can try this:

```
SELECT N as number
FROM my_table
WHERE IF(EXISTS (SELECT A FROM my_table WHERE A = 1 and B is NULL and C is NULL),
    A = 1 and B is NULL and C is NULL,
    IF(EXISTS (SELECT A FROM my_table WHERE B = 1 and C is NULL), B = 1 and C is NULL, C = 1))
```

But it's very likely to kill performance. So better just use three queries instead of one.

**UPD:** There's another (yet similar) approach:

```
SELECT N as number
FROM my_table
WHERE (
  A = 1
  AND B is NULL
  AND C is NULL
) OR (
  B = 1
  AND C is NULL
  AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT A FROM my_table WHERE A = 1 and B is NULL and C is NULL)
) OR (
  C = 1
  AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT A FROM my_table WHERE A = 1 and B is NULL and C is NULL)
  AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT A FROM my_table WHERE B = 1 and C is NULL)
)
```

Comment: Requirements are to do it in one query. Will try that thou! tell you what. Thanks for your response.

Comment: @ssedano in that case, please let me know whether the query I wrote works for you

Comment: works, thank you. I already +1ed you. But I'd like to wait if someone clarifies me the variables issue. And then compare the performance. If your answer is the one I choose to implement I will mark it as valid. If no more answers are given then yours gonna make it.

Comment: sorry my answer was not right. I want the exact opposite function.

Answer (score 0):

From the other sample and it's comments, I would approach your query this way.  The first query to pre-qualify if there are ANY "C = 1" values and store into a CCnt field.  If none found, force the CCnt value to NULL. SECOND, do the same against the "B" column.  Since each of these has a limit of 1, should be fast as long as it can FIND an entry of C=1 or B=1 respectively.  if not, their values are NULL.  Why do this way?  The query is done ONCE per run of the query and the answer is done.  It doesn't have to keep doing the query repeatedly as can be KILLER performance when used as sub-queries.  Doing a count() with no group by will GUARANTEE as single row, so you won't have any Cartesian result that could result in duplicates.

Now that this preemptive querying is done, now add in your main table.  At this point, the "HasCEntry.CCnt" value will either be a 1 or NULL.
"HasBEntry.CCnt" value will either be a 1 or NULL.

```
select 
      YT.*
   from
      ( select IF( count(*) > 0, 1, NULL ) as CCnt
           from YourTable
           where C = 1
           limit 1 ) HasCEntry,
      ( select IF( count(*) > 0, 1, NULL ) as BCnt
           from YourTable
           where B = 1
           limit 1 ) HasBEntry,
      YourTable YT
   where
            YT.C = 1
      OR  ( YT.B = 1 AND HasCEntry.CCnt IS NULL )
      OR  ( YT.A = 1 AND HasBEntry.BCnt IS NULL AND HasCEntry.CCnt IS NULL )
```

Now, following the WHERE clause.  If there is even 1 record where C=1, then the 
YT.C = 1 is all you need and its done... and the other "OR" conditions you don't care about, the record is coming along.

Now, say there are NO entries for C = 1.  We know the "CCnt" value is NULL, so that will come into the first "OR" condition and testing against "B"... B Specifically = 1 AND the CCnt IS NULL... So, if there was an entry for "C=2" (3, 4 or any other value), we don't want it.  We only want B = 1 AND C = NULL...

If C and B fail, then we fall into the "A" test.  Likewise, A = 1 AND B is null AND C is NULL for same reasons as B above.

For a small table, you might not notice any significant performance difference from Shedal's answer.  However, it COULD be a huge hit as your table grows.